# Python script doesn t compile when I run it with QProcess

Tags: python, c++, qt, opencv, qprocess

I want to run a python script with QProcess in my QT Project once I click a pushButton.
This is my code :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QProcess p;
        QStringList params;
        QString pythonPath = "C:/Python/python.exe";
        QString pythonScript = "C:\\Users\\melek\\Desktop\\user_interface\\user_interface-master\\jdid.py";
        params << pythonScript;
        QStringList arguments;
        p.start(pythonPath, params);
        p.waitForFinished(-1);
        QString p_stdout = p.readAll();
        QString output(p.readAllStandardOutput());
        QString p_stderr = p.readAllStandardError();
        if(!p_stderr.isEmpty())
           qDebug()<<"Python error:"<<p_stderr;
        qDebug()<<"Python result="<<p_stdout;
        qDebug()<<p_stdout;
        qDebug()<<output;
}
```

When I run the script in python ( pycharm it compiles and I get the correct result ). However, when I run from QT I receive the following error : 
Python error: "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"C:\Users\melek\Desktop\user_interface\user_interface-master\jdid.py\", line 27, in \r\n    template1 = cv2.cvtColor(template1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)\r\ncv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'\r\n\r\n"

This is the python script :

```
# python match.py --template cod_logo.png --images images

# import the necessary packages
import math as m
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import glob
import cv2




    # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#ap.add_argument("-t1", "--template1", required=True, help="Path to template image")
#ap.add_argument("-t2", "--template2", required=True, help="Path to template image")
#ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True,
#   help="Path to images where template will be matched")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--visualize",
    help="Flag indicating whether or not to visualize each iteration")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image image, convert it to grayscale, and detect edges
template1 = cv2.imread("start.png")
template1 = cv2.cvtColor(template1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template1 = cv2.Canny(template1, 50, 200)
(tH1, tW1) = template1.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow("Template1", template1)

template2 = cv2.imread("end.png")
template2 = cv2.cvtColor(template2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template2 = cv2.Canny(template2, 50, 200)
(tH2, tW2) = template2.shape[:2]
cv2.imshow("Template2", template2)

# loop over the images to find the template in

image1 = cv2.imread("test1.jpg")
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
found1 = None

    # loop over the scales of the image
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
    # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
    # of the ratio of the resizing
    resized1 = imutils.resize(gray1, width = int(gray1.shape[1] * scale))
    r1 = gray1.shape[1] / float(resized1.shape[1])

    # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
    # from the loop
    if resized1.shape[0] < tH1 or resized1.shape[1] < tW1:
        break

    # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
    # matching to find the template in the image
    edged1 = cv2.Canny(resized1, 50, 200)
    result1 = cv2.matchTemplate(edged1, template1, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    (_, maxVal1, _, maxLoc1) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result1)

    # check to see if the iteration should be visualized
    if args.get("visualize", False):
        # draw a bounding box around the detected region
        clone1 = np.dstack([edged1, edged1, edged1])
        cv2.rectangle(clone1, (maxLoc1[0], maxLoc1[1]),
            (maxLoc1[0] + tW1, maxLoc1[1] + tH1), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Visualize", clone1)
        cv2.waitKey()

    # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then ipdate
    # the bookkeeping variable
    if found1 is None or maxVal1 > found1[0]:
        found1 = (maxVal1, maxLoc1, r1)

# unpack the bookkeeping varaible and compute the (x, y) coordinates
# of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
(_, maxLoc1, r1) = found1
(startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc1[0] * r1), int(maxLoc1[1] * r1))
(endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc1[0] + tW1) * r1), int((maxLoc1[1] + tH1) * r1))

# draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
cv2.rectangle(image1, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image1", image1)
x_start = (startX + endX)/2
y_start = (startY + endY)/2
print("Start :( ",x_start," , ",y_start," )")
print("Dimensions : ", abs(startX - endX), " X ", abs(startY - endY))
cv2.waitKey()


image2 = cv2.imread("test1.jpg")
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
found2 = None

# loop over the scales of the image
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
    # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
    # of the ratio of the resizing
    resized2 = imutils.resize(gray2, width = int(gray2.shape[1] * scale))
    r2 = gray2.shape[1] / float(resized2.shape[1])

    # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
    # from the loop
    if resized2.shape[0] < tH2 or resized2.shape[1] < tW2:
        break

    # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
    # matching to find the template in the image
    edged2 = cv2.Canny(resized2, 50, 200)
    result2 = cv2.matchTemplate(edged2, template2, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
    (_, maxVal2, _, maxLoc2) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result2)

    # check to see if the iteration should be visualized
    if args.get("visualize", False):
        # draw a bounding box around the detected region
        clone2 = np.dstack([edged2, edged2, edged2])
        cv2.rectangle(clone2, (maxLoc2[0], maxLoc2[1]),
            (maxLoc2[0] + tW2, maxLoc2[1] + tH2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("Visualize", clone2)
        cv2.waitKey()

    # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then ipdate
    # the bookkeeping variable

    if found2 is None or maxVal2 > found2[0]:
        found2 = (maxVal2, maxLoc2, r2)


# unpack the bookkeeping varaible and compute the (x, y) coordinatesz
# of the bounding box based on the resized ratio

(_, maxLoc2, r2) = found2

(startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc2[0] * r2), int(maxLoc2[1] * r2))
(endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc2[0] + tW2) * r2), int((maxLoc2[1] + tH2) * r2))

# draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
cv2.rectangle(image2, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image2", image2)
x_end = (startX + endX)/2
y_end = (startY + endY)/2
print(" End :( ",x_end," , ",y_end," )")
print("Dimensions : ",abs(startX-endX)," X ",abs(startY-endY))
cv2.waitKey()

arrow = np.array([x_end - x_start, y_end - y_start])
vertical_line = np.array([0,1])
p = np.inner(arrow,vertical_line)
result_rad = np.arccos(p / (m.sqrt((x_end - x_start) * (x_end - x_start) + (y_end - y_start) * (y_end - y_start))))
result_deg = result_rad *180/ m.pi
if (x_end < x_start):
    result = result_deg + 180
elif(x_end > x_start) :
    result = result_deg
if (x_end == x_start):
    if (y_start<y_end):
        result = 0
    else :
        result = 180

print("Rotate camera by ",result," degrees in the direct way")
```

Comment: Your python script uses relative file paths, and so depends on the current working directory. My guess is, when you run it from your application, the current directory is not what you expect, and the script simply can't find the files.

Comment: You can explicitly set the current directory for the new process with `QProcess::setWorkingDirectory`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes it worked now with setWorkingDirectory thank you!